# Database Error No exception message supplied in Django with MongoDB - Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, pymongo

Im working on a Django project where i was using postgres and it was working fine. Now i want to use MongoDB but im getting **"No exception message supplied"** error most of times when querying on objects. please find the below codes for reference and help.

**Model**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_status = (('Pending', 'Pending'), ('Under Process', 'Under Process'), ('Dispatched', 
    'Dispatched'),
                    ('Delivered', 'Delivered'), ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled'), ('Out for 
    delivery', 
   'Out for delivery'))
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(ShippingAddress, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, 
    null=True, 
    blank=True)
    order_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=order_status, default='Pending', max_length=30)
    payment_status = models.CharField(choices=(('Received', 'Received'), ('Failed', 'Failed'), 
    ('Pending', 'Pending')),
                                      default='Pending', max_length=30)
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    coupon_applied = models.BooleanField(null=True,blank=True)
    coupon = 
    models.ForeignKey(ShoppingCoupon,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,null=True,blank=True)
    coupon_discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2, 
    null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    # Payment details captured from payment gateway
    payment_order_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True) # razorpay order id
    payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True) # Razorpay payment id
    payment_signature = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    ordered_medicine = models.JSONField(null=True,blank=True)
```

**Query**

```
def cartData(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.user_type == 'patient':
    patient = Patient.objects.select_related('user').get(user=request.user)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(patient=patient, complete=False) // Im 
    getting error here
    items = order.cartitem_set.select_related('medicine').all()
    cartItems = order.get_cart_items
```

im getting error on "**order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(patient=patient, complete=False)**"

Comment: You can use  `try except` bloc to achieve this goal too : `try: order = Order.objects.get(patient=patient, complete=False) except: Order.DoesNotExist as e:  print(e.message) order = Order(patient=patient, complete=False) order.save()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but this is not working

Comment: What is the error type. `ValueError` ? `TypeError` ? try to catch it in the except block too

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem `got_or_create` method doesn't work with django/mongo. especially `BooleanField`. If I delete `BooleanField` its working well.

Answer (score 0):

Django's Object Relational Mapping is mostly designed for relational databases like PostgreSQL or MySQL, and MongoDB is a NoSQL. For MongoDB with Django, there are packages like like "djongo" or "django-mongodb-engine." These provide compatibility layers needed to access the underlying DB.
I was thinking that if you intend to use MongoDB as the primary database, it might be more appropriate to use an ORM specifically designed for MongoDB, such as MongoEngine or PyMODM. These ORMs provide more resilience with a document-based structures and its query language. There may be no direct equivalent of `get_or_create()` so this may be a similar logic but for MongoDB:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

try:
    order = Order.objects.get(patient=patient, complete=False)
except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
    print(str(e))
    order = Order(patient=patient, complete=False)
    order.save()
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

You may be switching code packages already, so in that case, this may only work for MongoDB and Django ORM packages.